# How to delete multiple entries in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I have db with multiple entries.

I Google out something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*), item_id, text, number FROM ads
GROUP BY item_id, text, number
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

this select (I think) all my multiple entries, I use SQLyog, ... and there is no option to press button and delete **all results** of this query.

but even if **I select all one by one and delete**, I would also delete **original one**, right?

I basically want to keep **all unique entries** and keep one of multiple items.

simple example

*('1' 'Novi Sad' '123');
('1' 'Novi Sad' '123');
('3' 'Beograd' '124');*

I want to keep

*('1' 'Novi Sad' '123');
('3' 'Beograd' '124');*

I know only basic mysql.

Answer (score 1):

When you do delete entries make sure to reset your ID increment

```
ALTER TABLE 'table_name' AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you just copy, drop and delete?

```
CREATE TABLE Copy_Temp as
SELECT item_id, text, number 
FROM ads
GROUP BY item_id, text, number;

DROP Table ads;

RENAME TABLE Copy_Temp TO ads;
```

Answer (score 1):

Select all **unique** records into a temp table.
Delete all records from original table.
Insert all records from your temp table into original table.

Comment: This will select unique

SELECT COUNT(*), item_id, text, number FROM ads
GROUP BY item_id, text, number
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;

but, it will not select one item from multiple ones.

Comment: No, the query should be something like:

SELECT DISTINCT item_id, text, number FROM ads

Actually, your item_id should really be primary key and not repeat.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE emp FROM employee emp, employee emp2
WHERE emp.id > emp2.id
AND emp.name = emp2.name
```

For example, you having the table `employee` in which there are duplicate records (having the same name multiple times) then this query will delete all the duplicate records.